# Get Garbage Collector metrics using WMI

Tags: windows, garbage-collection, wmi

1. I need to collect metrics about the Percent Time in GarbageCollector using WMI Classes for Windows servers. I'm using the Class: "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory".
   Is this correct?
2. Then I take two samples for that class and i made the following calculation:

   ```
       # PSEUDO CODE
       PercentTime in GC = 
       (
         (sample2->'PercentTimeinGC' - sample1->'PercentTimeinGC') / 
         (sample2->'TimeStamp_Sys100NS' - sample1->'TimeStamp_Sys100NS')
       )
   ```

This calculation is definitively wrong, how to do it in the right way?

Tks in advance.

gulden

Answer (score 2):

After some digging in the unknown world of windows I've found the solution:

I've started with this link that explains the calculation methods for each kind of metric:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974615.aspx

However, we need to know the countertype, in this case the countertype for "PercentTimeinGC". To know that i need to run the WEBMTest.exe program:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180684.aspx

1. Connect to "root\CIMV2"
2. Open Class... "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory"
3. Select the property "PercentTimeinGC"
4. Click in the button "Show MOF"
5. Find the line:

   "[DisplayName("**% Time in GC**"): ToInstance, **countertype(537003008)**: ToInstance, perfindex(2606): ToInstance, helpindex(2607): ToInstance, defaultscale(0): ToInstance, perfdetail(100): ToInstance] uint32 PercentTimeinGC;"

Now that we know the countertype (**537003008**), you need to map it to a human readable form. This link will help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389383(v=vs.85).aspx

The mapping for coutertype 537003008 is PERF_RAW_FRACTION.

We go back for the first link and find the calculation method for PERF_RAW_FRACTION that is:

```
(100 * CounterValue) / BaseValue
```

I love windows.

gulden